# Python and MySQL : Error with simple INSERT

Tags: python, mysql, sql-insert, mysql-python

```
import mysql.connector
conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="password", database="database_name")
cursor = conn.cursor()
a = "abcd"
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table_jeux (lien_fiche) VALUES (?)", (a))
```

And this is the error I get when I execute the script :

```
ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): Syntax error near to '?)' at line 1
```

Thanks for help, I really don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What You probably want is to insert variable a into Your SQL code, but it doesn't work - and the parser gets a "?" where You want it to have "abcd"

You could try this:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table_jeux (lien_fiche) VALUES ({})".format(a))
```

or (in somewhat python2 manner):

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table_jeux (lien_fiche) VALUES (%s)", (a,))
```

as described here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html

Comment: The second one is working perfectly, I try it but it was without the comma. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using f strings,

It should look something like this:

```
cursor.execute(f'INSERT INTO student (student_name, student_email, courseid) VALUES ("{student_name}","{student_email}",{course_id})')
```

where student_name, student_email and course_id are all variables.

In your case:

```
cursor.execute(f'INSERT INTO table_jeux (lien_fiche) VALUES ("{a}")')
```

Comment: Maybe you are using Python 2?

Comment: Yes I am using python 2

Comment: Ah, that's the problem. Should have warned you that f strings are only available in Python 3. My bad, I won't try to find another solution as Ergaro has already answered.